# AFTSurvivalRegression (spark ML) can someone explain this behavior?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, survival-analysis

Took the direct example from spark ml documentation.

```
training = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1.218, 1.0, Vectors.dense(1.560, -0.605)),
    (2.949, 0.0, Vectors.dense(0.346, 2.158)),
    (3.627, 0.0, Vectors.dense(1.380, 0.231)),
    (0.273, 1.0, Vectors.dense(0.520, 1.151)),
    (4.199, 0.0, Vectors.dense(0.795, -0.226))], ["label", "censor", 
    "features"])
quantileProbabilities = [0.3, 0.6]
aft = AFTSurvivalRegression(quantileProbabilities=quantileProbabilities,
                            quantilesCol="quantiles")
#aft = AFTSurvivalRegression()
model = aft.fit(training)

# Print the coefficients, intercept and scale parameter for AFT survival regression
print("Coefficients: " + str(model.coefficients))
print("Intercept: " + str(model.intercept))
print("Scale: " + str(model.scale))
model.transform(training).show(truncate=False)
```

result is:

```
Coefficients: [-0.496304411053,0.198452172529]
Intercept: 2.6380898963056327
Scale: 1.5472363533632303
+-----+------+--------------+------------------+
|label|censor|features      |prediction        |
+-----+------+--------------+------------------+
|1.218|1.0   |[1.56,-0.605] |5.718985621018951 |
|2.949|0.0   |[0.346,2.158] |18.07678210850554 |
|3.627|0.0   |[1.38,0.231]  |7.381908879359964 |
|0.273|1.0   |[0.52,1.151]  |13.577717814884505|
|4.199|0.0   |[0.795,-0.226]|9.013087597344805 |
+-----+------+--------------+------------------+
```

But if we change the value of all labels as label + 20. as:

```
training = spark.createDataFrame([
    (21.218, 1.0, Vectors.dense(1.560, -0.605)),
    (22.949, 0.0, Vectors.dense(0.346, 2.158)),
    (23.627, 0.0, Vectors.dense(1.380, 0.231)),
    (20.273, 1.0, Vectors.dense(0.520, 1.151)),
    (24.199, 0.0, Vectors.dense(0.795, -0.226))], ["label", "censor", 
    "features"])
quantileProbabilities = [0.3, 0.6]
aft = AFTSurvivalRegression(quantileProbabilities=quantileProbabilities,
                             quantilesCol="quantiles")
#aft = AFTSurvivalRegression()
model = aft.fit(training)

# Print the coefficients, intercept and scale parameter for AFT survival regression
print("Coefficients: " + str(model.coefficients))
print("Intercept: " + str(model.intercept))
print("Scale: " + str(model.scale))
model.transform(training).show(truncate=False)
```

result changes to:

```
Coefficients: [23.9932020748,3.18105314757]
Intercept: 7.35052273751137
Scale: 7698609960.724161
+------+------+--------------+---------------------+---------+
|label |censor|features      |prediction           |quantiles|
+------+------+--------------+---------------------+---------+
|21.218|1.0   |[1.56,-0.605] |4.0912442688237169E18|[0.0,0.0]|
|22.949|0.0   |[0.346,2.158] |6.011158613411288E9  |[0.0,0.0]|
|23.627|0.0   |[1.38,0.231]  |7.7835948690311181E17|[0.0,0.0]|
|20.273|1.0   |[0.52,1.151]  |1.5880852723124176E10|[0.0,0.0]|
|24.199|0.0   |[0.795,-0.226]|1.4590190884193677E11|[0.0,0.0]|
+------+------+--------------+---------------------+---------+
```

Can someone please explain this exponential blow up in prediction, as per my understanding prediction in AFT is prediction of time when the failure event will occur, not able to understand why it will change exponentialy against value of label.

Comment: what does "label" correspond to in these examples? is it the time index?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the result I get when running your 2nd example with Spark2.1 :

```py
    Coefficients: [-0.065814695216,0.00326705958509]
    Intercept: 3.29140205698
    Scale: 0.109856123692
    +------+------+--------------+------------------+---------------------------------------+
    |label |censor|features      |prediction        |quantiles                              |
    +------+------+--------------+------------------+---------------------------------------+
    |21.218|1.0   |[1.56,-0.605] |24.20972861807431 |[21.61744311047112,23.97833624826161]  |
    |22.949|0.0   |[0.346,2.158] |26.461225875981274|[23.6278586196251,26.208314087493847]  |
    |23.627|0.0   |[1.38,0.231]  |24.565240805031486|[21.93488840685864,24.330450511651154] |
    |20.273|1.0   |[0.52,1.151]  |26.074003958175602|[23.282098949562453,25.82479316934075] |
    |24.199|0.0   |[0.795,-0.226]|25.491396901107066|[22.761875236582235,25.247754569057975]|
    +------+------+--------------+------------------+---------------------------------------+
```

The `ParamMap`of the model is:

```py
aft.extractParamMap()

    {Param(parent=u'AFTSurvivalRegression_4a8b957cf888792bb1b8', name='censorCol', doc='censor column name. The value of this column could be 0 or 1. If the value is 1, it means the event has occurred i.e. uncensored; otherwise censored.'): 'censor',
     Param(parent=u'AFTSurvivalRegression_4a8b957cf888792bb1b8', name='maxIter', doc='max number of iterations (>= 0).'): 100,
     Param(parent=u'AFTSurvivalRegression_4a8b957cf888792bb1b8', name='fitIntercept', doc='whether to fit an intercept term.'): True,
     Param(parent=u'AFTSurvivalRegression_4a8b957cf888792bb1b8', name='aggregationDepth', doc='suggested depth for treeAggregate (>= 2).'): 2,
     Param(parent=u'AFTSurvivalRegression_4a8b957cf888792bb1b8', name='labelCol', doc='label column name.'): 'label',
     Param(parent=u'AFTSurvivalRegression_4a8b957cf888792bb1b8', name='featuresCol', doc='features column name.'): 'features',
     Param(parent=u'AFTSurvivalRegression_4a8b957cf888792bb1b8', name='quantilesCol', doc='quantiles column name. This column will output quantiles of corresponding quantileProbabilities if it is set.'): 'quantiles',
     Param(parent=u'AFTSurvivalRegression_4a8b957cf888792bb1b8', name='tol', doc='the convergence tolerance for iterative algorithms (>= 0).'): 1e-06,
     Param(parent=u'AFTSurvivalRegression_4a8b957cf888792bb1b8', name='quantileProbabilities', doc='quantile probabilities array. Values of the quantile probabilities array should be in the range (0, 1) and the array should be non-empty.'): [0.3,
      0.6],
     Param(parent=u'AFTSurvivalRegression_4a8b957cf888792bb1b8', name='predictionCol', doc='prediction column name.'): 'prediction'}
```

Can you check the convergence tolerance, the maximum number of iterations and whether to fit an intercept term?

Comment: What are the values you are using for `quantileProbabilities`? I don't see any difference in my result using `quantileProbabilities = [0.3, 0.6]`, given for example.

Comment: I used exactly the same values as the ones in your second example. I have an extra column and different predictions. Did you add some transformations?

Comment: Can you please paste your code in the answer, I had actually removed `quantileProbabilities` earlier, but again after using them also is not making any difference for me.

Comment: Also, can you tell me which Spark version you are using, I'm using Spark 2.2.0.

Comment: I've updated my result and have added `quantiles` values which I'm getting.

Comment: I was trying to reproduce the result on my computer I now get your initial result

Comment: with python 3.6 and spark2.2 instead of python 2.7 and i think spark 2.2

Comment: Oh! Where did you get the result which you have posted in the answer? I'm not able to get that result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153652/discussion-between-marie-and-ashish-chopra).